# Child component does not re-render when props change in store

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I am using Vue-js with require-js. I am trying to get data from vuex store into my **cart component** and render a component for each item in the store. But when I trigger a mutation from my **body component** to change the store, the data is being changed and the props of my  **cart component** change, but the UI does not re-render.

This is my store:

```
    state: {
      users: {
        user1: {
           item: { date:null }
        }
      }
   }
   mutations: { setDate:function(state,payload){ 
              var newState = state.users;
              newState[user][item].date = payload.date
              state.users = Object.assign({},newState)
           } }
```

This is my cart component:

```
<template>
    <div v-if="activeStep==1">
        <p> Service Time: {{service.ServiceTime}} Min.</p>
        <p>Date: {{service.date || 'Not Selected'}}  </p>
        <p>Time: {{service.time || 'Not Selected'}}  </p>
        <p>Prefered Staff:  {{service.staff}} </p>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

    define(['Vue','vuex'],function(Vue,vuex){
        return {
            template: template,
            computed: vuex.mapState(['activeStep']),
            props: ['service'],

        }
    })
</script>
```

This is the parent of my cart component:

```
<template>
    <div class="cart-user-body" >

            <div class="cart-service" v-for="(service,key,index) in users[user]" :key="index">
              <div class="cart-service-body">
                    <service-book-details :service="service"></service-book-details>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


</template>



<script>
    define([
        'Vue','vuex','vue!./serviceBookDetails'
    ], function(Vue,vuex,serviceBookDetails) {
        return {

            template:template,
            components: {
                'service-book-details': serviceBookDetails
            },
            props: ['user'],
            computed: vuex.mapState(['users']),
        }        
    });
</script>
```

This is how I am triggering the mutation from my body component:

```
addDate(e) {
        var payload = {
          date: moment(e, "DD/MM/YYYY").format("Do MMMM YYYY"),
          id: this.$data.class,
          name: this.username
        };
        this.$store.commit("setDate", payload);
      },
```

I even tried using **Vue.set(state,'users',newState)** but the UI does not re-render.

I have checked the Vue dev tools and I see that upon triggering the mutation, the props of my **cart component** have updated but it does not show on the UI.

If I try using **getters**, the key to the object does not exist as my store does not have the required data until user interacts with UI and adds data. And my **cart component** is always showing since the start so it shows me an error saying `cant read property item of undefined`.

Am I doing anything wrong or is there a different way to make it work.

Comment: In this line, `newState[user][item].date = payload.date`, where are `user` and `item` defined?

Comment: I have not put the exact code. Here is the exact mutation: `setDate:function(state,payload){
                var newState = state.users;
                newState[payload.name][payload.id].date = payload.date
               state.users = Object.assign({},state.users,newState)
                // Vue.set(state,'users',newState)
            },`

Answer (score 1):

You can't use array indexing for setting values with Vue.  It is a restriction caused by Javascript.

This will not be reactive if `user` and or `item` did not exist when you created your store.

```
newState[user][item].date =
```

Instead, you need to use:

```
Vue.set(object, key, value)
```

In your case, you first need to ensure you set `user` and `item` with that method **before** assigning to `date`.

Comment: When I am calling the mutation, state[user][id] exists in the store. Do you mean I should I use `Vue.set(newState[payload.name][payload.id],date,payload.date)` to set the value in my newState, and then assign it to state.users?

Comment: And also, my store is of the format: `state:{ users:{ [guest-name]:{ [itemID]:{ date:null } }}}`

Comment: @abhirham I would suggest you put a breakpoint at `newState[user][item].date = payload.date` and then inspect `newState` with chrome's debugger (not vue tools).  Make sure that Vue has sunk it's teeth into the entire tree.  There should only be proxies to objects, not plain objects.  If you see a plain object, you will know that the state is not reactive.